# difference between check mark and tick mark

Tags: meaning, difference

What is exact difference between tick mark and check mark. I know about ticking something as done and marking as checked. I thing both are same but what is exact difference.

Explanatory comments are most welcome.

Comment: [Related question on EL&U](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/367651/116151).

Answer (score 2):

They are the exact same thing. Tick mark tends to be said more commonly by British people and check mark tends to be more commonly said by Americans. Additionally, as a native American English speaker, I do find myself saying "tick the box" once in a while, but at the same time I personally never say "tick mark."

See [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/74434/20982) for further reference.

Comment: As a British person I would always just say a 'tick' not a 'tick mark'.